# Breadth-First Search for Six Degrees of Separation in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, graph-algorithm, breadth-first-search

I have a video-game themed Six Degrees of Separation app and I want to know the best way to implement breadth-first search using node.js and MongoDB.

My app uses https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native for MongoDB.

For the collection that I'm using, my documents look like this:

```
{
  _id: "Mega Man",
  with: [
          { _id: "Wolverine", in: "Marvel vs. Capcom"},
          { _id: "Snake Man", in: "Mega Man's Soccer"}
        ]
}
```

If I want the characters related to Mega Man, I'd need a query to produce

```
[
  { _id: "Wolverine", with: [...]},
  { _id: "Snake Man", with: [...]}
]
```

So:

1. What query/queries would I use to get a list of characters, each one with an `_id` corresponding to the `_id`s in the `with` field of any given character?
2. How would I query the database if I want to get all the characters that are `n` steps away from a given node?

Comment: It sounds like you want a graph database like Neo4j and not MonogoDb. http://www.neo4j.org/

Comment: Neo4j isn't available on AppFog, where my app is being hosted.

Comment: Maybe you'll need to find a new host. MongoDB isn't a good fit for the 2nd query in particular.

Comment: You also can't do query #1 as a single step if I follow it. (Do you mean a MongoDB document when you say "node?")

Comment: Yeah, I meant document. I was thinking in terms of a graph.